# Rspec/FactoryGirl testing order by created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I'm trying to test ordering collection by `created_at`. As it's timestamp with precision to the second, when I create 10 records they have the same `created_at` value which leads me to inconsistent response. So what I'm doing here is I set `created_at` field manually like

```
5.times do |t|
  create(:model, created_at: Time.current.advance(days: -1*(t+1))
end
```

and it set `created_at` just fine but when I do

`Model.all.order(created_at: :desc)` it just ignores it and put in `ASC` order.

Is there any way to test this order as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that the timestamp you're providing isn't being saved, and that Rails is using its own internal timestamps as the objects are created. You might try:

```
5.times do |t|
  thing = create(:model)
  thing.update_column(:created_at, Time.current.advance(days: -1*(t+1))
end
```

This will bypass any validation on the model and you should be saving the correct timestamps, and you should then be able to order them as expected.

You can test by saving results of the query in the variable `results` and then something like:

```
expect(results[0].created_at < results[1].created_at).to be true
```

Another thing you might try is `YourModel.unscope.where(...).order(created_at: :desc)`. There may be a scope that you can't see that is affecting the order.

Comment: It is saved. Seems that some default ordering is activated or so. I'm checking it right now.

Comment: Another thing you might try is `YourModel.unscope.order(created_at: :desc)`. There may be a scope that you can't see that is affecting the order

Comment: Yes exactly, I just did it and that's it.